# INSERT SELECT and IGNORE_DUP_KEY, how can I retrieve discarded rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Using MS-SQL, I have an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement that populates a table that has a unique key with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON`.

Is there an **easy** way I could get the rows that were discarded because they were duplicated? (Preferably after the statement has completed)

Comment: What sql do you use ? mysql ? sql server 2012 ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: It needs to be compatible with MS-SQL 2005, 2008 and 2012

Comment: @MartinSmith: I use IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF in order to prevent the INSERT SELECT from failing.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Sorry, you are right. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

The [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) is the key here.

```
create table dbo.IDKsource ( 
    SNumber int not null, 
    SText varchar(100) not null  
) ;
go
insert into dbo.IDKsource 
values ( 1, 'aaaaa' ), ( 2, 'bbbbb' ), ( 1, 'cccccc' ), ( 3, 'dddddd' ) ;
go

create table dbo.IDKOntarget ( 
    SNumber int not null unique with ( ignore_dup_key = on ), 
    SText varchar(100) not null
) ;
go

-- The following lines must all be in one batch!
declare @RecordsWereInserted table (
    SNumber int not null , 
    SText varchar(100) not null
) ;

insert into dbo.IDKOntarget ( SNumber , SText )
output inserted.* into @RecordsWereInserted 
select SNumber , SText 
from dbo.IDKSource ;

select SNumber , SText 
from dbo.IDKsource 
except 
select SNumber , SText 
from @RecordsWereInserted ;
```

If you want to keep the inserted data for longer than one batch (or your version of SQL Server does not support table variables) then replace my table variable RecordsWereInserted with an actual table.

Note: My first approach was to use the INSERT statement directly with the EXCEPT but SQL Server will not allow DML statements with EXCEPT, INTERSECT or UNION.

Comment: +1 That's interesting I didn't realise that `output inserted` would also include the rows that weren't actually inserted due to `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`

Comment: It doesn't, Martin, which is why we have to use an EXCEPT query.

Comment: Ah I see I wasn't looking at it properly. I thought you were taking the result of the output and performing an `EXCEPT` against the base table.